# url redirect none www to www

Tags: url-rewriting, urls

In my general settings the url shows without www

[image]

If I put www like this

[image]

Do I need to do .htaccess mod_rewrite to redirect my none www(example.com) doamin to redirect www (www.example.com) or is this properly handle url redirect?

Answer (score 0):

IMO, going to your `.htaccess` file is not necessary.

You can instead **flush permalink rules** in the Permalink Settings area of your site. Just click on Permalinks, select a new option (other than the current one you're using), save... Click on Permalinks again, choose your previous option, and then save again. And that does it!.